# No continuation using the captured GUI context but why is there deadlock?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am wondering why there is deadlock in the following case in which no continuation using the captured GUI context.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;
}

async Task DelayAsync()
{
    // GUI context is captured here (right before the following await)
    await Task.Delay(3000);//.ConfigureAwait(false);
    // As no  code follows the preceding await, there is no continuation that uses the captured GUI context. 
}

private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task t = DelayAsync();

    t.Wait();
}
```

## Edit:

I know the deadlock can be solved by either

- using `await Task.Delay(3000).ConfigureAwait(false);` or
- replacing `t.Wait();` with `await t;`.

But it is not the question. The question is

Why is there the deadlock while there is no continuation that will use the captured GUI context? In my mental model, if there is continuation, then it will use the captured GUI context so it will cause deadlock.

Comment: I am a little confused with the sample code. you are mixing async with a blocking call `.Wait()`. It needs to be async all the way up to avoid the deadlock.

Comment: `await DelayAsync();`  in the async event handler and all should be fine.

Comment: @Nkosi: I am not asking how to fix the deadlock.

Comment: What do you mean by "GUI context is captured here"?

Comment: @Enigmativity: As the asynchronous `DelayAsync()` is called in `Button1_Click()` so  any synchronous code before the first await in `DelayAsync` will run in the GUI context. The GUI context is captured at that point. And if `ConfigureAwait(false)` is not invoked by the `await Task.Delay(3000)` then the continuation will run in GUI context.

Comment: @ArtificialHairlessArmpit - OK, so that's just the normal behaviour. You're not doing anything weird there.

Comment: @Enigmativity: In other simpler words, what causes the deadlock?

Comment: You capture the context when you click the button then wait but the `DelayAsync` call is waiting for the context to be available before it can complete it's task. But that is blocked in the button click event and will always be blocked. It doesn't matter what comes after `await Task.Delay(3000)`

Comment: Have you seen [What Causes the Deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)?

Comment: @Crowcoder: I have read the link multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `async` works with awaiters, not with tasks. Because of that, it needs an extra bit of logic at the end of the method to translate the status of the awaiter to the task.

---

Your assumption that there is no continuation is false. It would be true if you just returned the task:

```
Task DelayAsync()
{
    return Task.Delay(3000);
}
```

However, things get more complicated when you mark the method as `async`. One important property of `async` method is the way it handles exceptions. Consider those methods for instance:

```
Task NoAsync()
{
    throw new Exception();
}

async Task Async()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Now what happens if you invoke them?

```
var task1 = NoAsync(); // Throws an exception
var task2 = Async(); // Returns a faulted task
```

The difference is that the async version wraps the exception in the returned task.

How is it relevant to our case?

When you `await` a method, the compiler actually calls `GetAwaiter()` on the object you're awaiting. The awaiter defines 3 members:

- The `IsCompleted` property
- The `OnCompleted` method
- The `GetResult` method

As you can see, there is no member directly returning an exception. How to know whether an awaiter is faulted? To know that, you need to call the `GetResult` method, which will throw the exception.

Back to your example:

```
async Task DelayAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
}
```

If `Task.Delay` throws an exception, the `async` machinery needs to set the status of the returned task as faulted. To know whether `Task.Delay` threw an exception, it needs to call `GetResult` on the awaiter after `Task.Delay` is complete. Therefore you have a continuation, though it's not apparent when seeing the code. Under the hood, the async method looks like:

```
Task DelayAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    try
    {
        var awaiter = Task.Delay(3000).GetAwaiter();

        awaiter.OnCompleted(() =>
        {
            // This is the continuation that causes your deadlock
            try
            {
                awaiter.GetResult();
                tcs.SetResult(null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tcs.SetException(ex);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tcs.SetException(ex);
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

The actual code is more complex, and uses a `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<T>` instead of `TaskCompletionSource<T>`, but the idea is the same.